# Icon png files to point clouds with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I need to get point representation of png icons.
I have little knowledge about image processing.

There are some requirements,
There should be a point in the corners.
Points should equally spaced on the edges.
I should have control over point density.

for example, i need points like white lines. Equally spaced and not skipping the corners.[example icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEech.jpg)

I tried using open CV findContours and I am a bit lost on the documentation. Can you guys help me what should I do? Or give me a direction for how can i detect edges and generate points on the edges equally spaced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.